# Trying to learn the "making of navigation bar"

Tags: html, css, navbar

I read some articles but couldn't understand them clearly.
There are some things I want my navigation bar to have,

1. The background color of the navigation bar shouldn't have a gap above and on the sides
   [image]
2. I want the elements to be in center but with a some gap between each other.

```css
#nav_bar {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Product Landing Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="nav_bar" class="nav_class">
    <a href="#welcome">Home</a>
    <a href="#product-info">Products</a>
    <a href="#product-pricing">Pricings</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>

  <section class="welcome">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

What are different ways to make a good navigation bar?

I have tried to read various articles from many websitA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space is from body element's default margins, you can reset it to 0:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

For the navigation, you can use flex to center it as well as giving some space between each item:

```css
#nav_bar {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Here is an example with the above tweaks:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav_bar {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_bar" class="nav_class">
  <a href="#welcome">Home</a>
  <a href="#product-info">Products</a>
  <a href="#product-pricing">Pricings</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
</nav>

<section class="welcome">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua that helped! Can you also tell why does the horizontal bar come when giving background color to the navigation bar?

Comment: Giving background color to an element won't create a scrollbar since the background color (or image) is always contained within the element. The possible cause could be the fixed width of an element or the content that somehow doesn't wrap. You can ask a new question and I will try to answer if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav_bar {
background-color: aliceblue;
padding: 14px 16px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
column-gap: 30px;
```

}

i think this work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).